# Is there a way to trap a super-being like Dr Manhattan?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

This linked video explains who and what Dr Manhattan is and what are his super-powers [Dr. Manhattan’s Superpowers EXPLAINED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4QhfwpvdrI).

[Dr Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Manhattan) character is from *Watchmen*

Here some quotes from Wikipedia link:

> **Powers and abilities**
>
> Jon is the only character in *Watchmen* to possess superpowers.
>   Throughout *Watchmen*, he is shown to be absolutely powerful and
>   invulnerable to all harm; even when his body is disintegrated, he can
>   reconstruct it in a matter of seconds and remains unharmed. He is
>   capable of altering his size depending on his needs, for example,
>   reconstructing himself in a much bigger form. He can hurl huge objects
>   effortlessly with his hands. He is also unable to exhaust himself. Jon
>   has complete awareness of and control over atomic and subatomic
>   particles. He is also an omnikinetic. He does not need air, water,
>   food or sleep, and is immortal. He can teleport himself and others
>   over limitless distances. He is also capable of true flight, although
>   he uses only levitation in most of his appearances. Due to his
>   perception of time, he sees his past, present and future
>   simultaneously.
>
> In addition to these powers, Jon is able to phase any part of his body
>   through solid objects without damaging them, produce multiple copies
>   of himself which function independently of each other, project
>   destructive energy, disintegrate people, create force fields,
>   transmute, create and destroy matter, move objects without physically
>   touching them (telekinesis), reverse entropy, repair anything no
>   matter how severe the damage is, and, he suggests, create life. He
>   also claims to have walked on the surface of the sun. At one point it
>   is stated that, in the event of a nuclear war, he would be capable of
>   destroying Soviet nuclear missiles while at the same time 'destroying'
>   large areas of Russia. As a result of these capabilities, Jon becomes
>   central to the United States' Cold War strategy of deterrence.
>
> He is also capable of manipulating reality as he sees fit, as seen
>   when he erased ten years from the DC Universe, when Barry Allen tried
>   to bring his original universe back to normal. The intervention of Jon
>   caused The New 52 timeline to be formed, within which most superheroes
>   are younger and less experienced, and most of them lose their most
>   important relationships before they even begin. Even Mister Mxyzptlk
>   himself acknowledges Jon to be far more powerful than him.[25] Such
>   power makes him one of the most powerful beings in the DC Multiverse.
>
> **Scientific accuracy**
>
> In the 2009 film adaptation *Watchmen*, physics professor James Kakalios
>   of the University of Minnesota was used as a scientific consultant,
>   and shed light on the potential scientific explanations of Doctor
>   Manhattan's powers both in the film and the comic. Cherenkov radiation
>   inspired Doctor Manhattan's appearance in the 2009 film adaptation.
>
> Kakalios explained that the intrinsic field has basis in reality in
>   that it is a representation of a collection of the electromagnetic,
>   and strong and weak nuclear forces. Kakalios explained that if a being
>   were able to manipulate matter, such a being would have complete
>   control over these three forces; hence, the "intrinsic field" would
>   exist. Kakalios also explained that while it is unlikely, Doctor
>   Manhattan's teleportation abilities could seemingly be achieved
>   through quantum tunnelling, should Doctor Manhattan have control over
>   his probability wave functions.

Basically my God is similar like him and I want to know is there a way to contain or trap something like him.

Please explain the method to achieve it, even better if it can be done or create by human, it's not necessary using today's technology, but at least achievable in the future or might be theoretically possible.

Feel free to edit the tag because I don't know which tags are more appropriate for this question.

Comment: You seem to have the answer in your question already.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica really ? can you point it out ? i dont realize it. i dont have much knowldege about this kind of thing after all.

Comment: It's the scientific accuracy part you quoted

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica would help a lot if you copy paste the line you mean, or elaborate it, because i still dont get it, as i say iam not knowledgeable about this thing.

Comment: By "seal" I presume you mean "contain" or "trap" a Dr Manhattan-like super-being? if you have created a fictional god of this sort, then you're probably looking to find ways of making life difficult for it. If I'm wrong, you can let me know.

Comment: @a4android yeah i mean contain or trap  thanks

Comment: You might be interested in reading the short story ["Diplomatic Immunity" by Robert Sheckley](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32040). In it, an alien messenger comes to Earth to attempt to enlist them into a galactic empire. Earth refuses and tries to "shoot the messenger" but that, alongside *many* other attempt fails, as the alien has extraordinary powers to avoid harm. The titular diplomatic immunity but it extends to all methods of harm while Earth scientists are racing to find a way to destroy the alien.

Answer (score 13):

You are attempting to contain a **creature that can do everything it can imagine. All you have to do is to make escape unimaginable for it.** Lock it into a pattern of behaviour. Trick it into thinking that whatever you do makes it powerless. As soon as it believes this, its godlike powers will make that reality. It will imprison itself.

This is the idea behi d the containment of [Item #: SCP-2845: The Deer](https://youtu.be/cVq4sPIXrLk). The deer is a god like beeing like Dr. Manhattan. As it came down to Earth it reaveged the land until it was lead into a trap. A geometric structure serves as containment. The containment is essentially a combination of oddly specific architecture, childish rituals and human sacrifice. What they do really doesn't matter. It matter that they began doing it and continue to do it in a precisely timed and scripted manner. Read the text below and the article for further explanation.

> I have been approached several times already in regards to the containment procedures and their complexity. I have been asked if all of the procedures are truly necessary, if they could not be cut down or edited for simplicity, and at least one claim that they were “patently ridiculous”.
>   This is my response, and I expect that it will be seen by all of the Foundation staff working on this project. I will not repeat myself, and I find it sickening that after all the struggle to contain this creature, pencil-pushing bureaucrats are still seeking to cut corners where they cannot be afforded to be cut.
>   The answer is no: The ritual will remain as it is, and will not be changed in any way. It cannot be cut down further, nor can it be added to. It has been set in place, and now that it has begun any deviation at all could very easily be catastrophic.
>   Rituals do not work because of some underlying laws, such as those that science operates on. Rituals work because they are rituals. They work because an arbitrary set of criteria has been met with exacting care. Belief that meeting these arbitrary criteria achieves a certain end assigns power to the ritual. The actions that were once meaningless now have been assigned Meaning through their repetition and application.
>   This is how one seals away a god, and this is a god. I know that the Foundation does not approve of using the term, but it is still the case. The Stag is a god, and it is not a petty local god. It is not one of the mild gods of Earth, or some weaker spirit that is bound by the strength of man’s belief.
>   We have, for the time being, fooled it into thinking that we have overpowered it. It does not understand that we do so falsely: it is a god. For gods, words have Power. Ritual and belief hold greater power over a god than all the laws of science.
>   However, it must be kept in mind that the Stag could escape, right now, if it so chose. With a thought, this entire facility could turn into a puff of hydrogen. If at any point the Stag thought to escape, it would, and we would be powerless to stop it.
>   However, it will not think to escape, or even to change its strategy. The idea will not even pass through its mind. It cannot comprehend the concept. It does not think in the way we think. Truth be told, I would not say that it thinks at all. This is an old god, it does not dabble in decisions. Decisions are for creatures who may act erratically, variably, or out of line. A god of this strength simply Is. It is an absolute. It acts as a force. In building this ritual, we have shifted its being the slightest bit, and now it is locked into a pattern of behavior: it struggles against us, we struggle against it, and we are locked together in an eternal dance so long as the ritual remains intact.
>   If one thing goes awry, the entirety is lost, and the deadlock is broken. Unstoppable force without an immovable object.
>   The rituals might seem to be nonsense, but they are what I divined to be the best course of action. There are powerful symbols there, and whether or not you or I think they are appropriate to the situation is irrelevant. I have listened to the converted, and I have listened to the echoes of the Stag in their songs. They are not suffering, but they are no longer human. They are changed utterly.
>   The ritual remains as it is.

Addendum: Use those tachyon blockers to prevent Dr. Manhattan or your god from seeing his imprisoned future.

Comment: If done right allowing the god to see its imprisoned future may be the key to imprisoning it in the first place. If they believe their future is predestined then being able to see that the rest of their future is spent in the trap would be the whole reason they step into and remain inside the trap. Gah. My brain.

Comment: In a less SCP-related example, this is how Earth's superheroes always beat the alien Shi'ar superhuman Gladiator in the Marvel Universe. Gladiator can do anything he believes he can do, so the key to beating him is to make him doubt his own abilities or gaslight him into believing he's found something stronger than him. He believes he is weaker than it, and thus it is so.

Answer (score 5):

If there is a way it has to be a black hole. As long as he is within the event horizon he could still teleport out, but he moment his form and consciousness are absorbed into the singularity we would have the equivalent of an unstoppable force meeting an unmoveable object. Or in this case an object that can escape anything through his wave potential manipulation meeting a point where that might not be possible.

Only events at the event horizon are able to do anything to "free" Manhattan then by evaporating the black hole. But these events might even destroy Manhattan within the black hole if a black hole evaporation destroys quantum informatio. If it does not destroy quantum information than Manhattan will escape once the black hole evaporates. Since Manhattan has to physically see and be present to make most stuff happen and his physical form of consciousness is trapped in the sigularity he might be trapped forever.

Again, this is speculation because no one truly knows what the singularity is. If the math (or some of it) is correct and it is basically a hole in the universe where the quantum field might not exist it could trap him. If the potentials still exist then he could simply teleport out.

Comment: They've disassembled Dr. Manhattan in the comics, atom by atom. He shrugged it off. A black hole would do jack against him. Good thought, but unfortunately, comic book writers don't science well.

Comment: @Halfthawed yes they did disassemble him, but his "consciousness" was still free to roam around. I already mentioned that just entering the event horizon would still allow him to escape, but the singularity could be what traps him as the singularity might have the physics (or lack thereoff) required. Manhattan's consciousness isnt everywhere even when he's deatomized, it has a kind of location. Put that location into a BH singularity and the potential physics can trap him.

Comment: Just getting him inside the event horizon may work - Dr. Manhattan has complete control over electromagnetism and the nuclear forces, but there is no direct evidence that he can manipulate gravity, travel faster than light or through time.  He can *see* the future, but this appears to be a passive ability, which is why a burst of tachyons could disrupt it.  He can teleport through quantum tunneling, but quantum waveforms are still limited by the speed of light.  As such, he should not be able to escape a black hole. *Getting* him into a black hole, on the other hand, is still a problem...

Answer (score 3):

**Psychological warfare**

The Wikipedia article is wrong. It left out his most important power. He can see the future. *Perfectly.* In Watchmen, he knows the entire plot ahead of time, but it's a double-edged sword - he can't *affect* the future (what?). The way it works is that he sees the future, and since he knows the future, he acts as if he knows the futures, so his seeing the future is him acting on it. In other words, as the plot reveals, nothing Dr. Manhattan does ever surprises him. He knows that the main villain of Watchmen is Ozymandius, but he also knows that he never tells anyone, so he can't.

If you don't get why this is, it basically gets spelled out in a GL comic during the Darkseid War event (which Alan Moore apparently has nothing to do with, but it's the same principle). Essentially, Alan Moore is using Dr. Manhattan for his concept of how God exists, and is powerless because of his omnipresence. (That is, of course, Alan Moore's opinion and while I disagree with it, the correctness of the philosophy has no bearing on Dr. Manhattan's power.)

Now, see, this is even weirder, because despite Dr. Manhattan knowing all of this, how he reacts to it is different depending on the time depending on his emotional states, which is even weirder. For instance, he gets inspired for renewed interest in humanity because of interactions with the Silk Spectre II. And as such, he goes to stop the main antagonist of the comic, but fails, because he's too late. (In turns out that the antagonist was using tachyon particles to cloud the exact future so Dr. Manhattan fails at that point). But, according to his powers, he knew that he'd have his mind changed, and thus help the humans - but until that event happened, he didn't care too.

Which means that the way to get Dr. Manhattan not to help is to get him in isolation mode by destroying his trust in humanity and then stopping anyone from interacting with him. (Which was the villain's plan all along, it just failed because Dr. Manhattan had a relationship with Silk Spectre at the time.)

This also means that the Doomsday Clock event in DC Comics makes no sense and was just a cash grab off Watchmen, because it's essentially just Dr. Manhattan screwing with the DC universe because Dr. Manhattan is bored. (It's still ongoing.)

In summary, comics are weird, and I know far too much about them.

Comment: Isnt there a whole plotpoint about ozymandias disrupting his future sight and people fearing its global nuclear war that has disrupting it?

Comment: Kind of. Tachyons can block his sight of the future (somehow?) and the 'nuclear global war' thing is the antagonist's plan to threaten everyone into peace. (Which, according to Doomsday Clock, fails spectacularly.) 'Look upon my works, ye mighty, and despair', indeed.

Answer (score 3):

## Love

In both comics and movie, there was only one power greater than Dr. Manhattan's: his relationship with Laurie. Not in the sense that she could manhandle him, but in the sense that his drive for protecting humanity and doing anything at all was his love for her and the need to have that feeling reciprocated. Once that love was over, Manhattan left the Earth for good.

What you need to trap your character is another character that he can love. Whomever controls his beloved controls him.

Comment: That is the difference between Manhattan and the Stag in the scp linked by @TheDyingOfLight.  Although a god, Manhattan is still fundamentally human.  The Stag is not.

Answer (score -1):

### How Big is a Rock?

Dr. Manhattan was tricked, by presenting him with a scenario that he believed, and didn't examine more closely. He was then overpowered by the same McGuffin that originally empowered him.

The first is an outcome of his peculiar psychology and environment, the second is purely a plot device. In either case, it doesn't generalize. Just like there is no "general rule" about why Superman is affected by Kryptonite, there is no general rule about how nigh-omniscient and nigh-omnipotent beings behave.